# How do I compute convergence of taylor series generated by f(x) = x^5(sin(2x)) at x = 0?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that the taylor series for sin is:

[x^(2n+1)]/(2n+1)!

I know that 2x can just be plugged in for x. What happens to the x^5?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\Rightarrow\sin(2x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Then $x^5\sin(2x)=2x^5\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^nx^{2n+6}}{(2n+1)!}$